# React: How to add onClick() on img tag of dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add `onClick()` on `<img>` of a html string which display via `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. I do it like this:

```
onClickBlowUpImage(e) {
    console.log('test')
}

render() {
    const finalContent = this.state.content.replace(/<img/g, '<img id="content_img" onClick={this.onClickBlowUpImage.bind(this)}')

    return (
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: finalContent }}></div>
    )
}
```

but code above will print this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined at HTMLImageElement.onclick`.

what is the right way?

Comment: I suppose you could split the string on the `img` tag and extract it from the string so you can render it in jsx. Then render string-first-half -> jsx img tag w/handler -> string-second half. Pretty hacky but...

Comment: If your component has a constructor, you should bind the function there. I think inlining the bind is something like `onClick={ () => this.onClickBlowUpImage.bind(this) }`. This is typically bad practice, though.

Comment: Why don't you just add the event listener to the <div> itself?

`<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: finalContent }} onClick={this.onClickBlowUpImage.bind(this)} />`.

Be aware of binding directly in JSX markup, though. It can cause unnecessary component updates. You should bind in a constructor or assign an arrow function to property.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion of function binds

Answer (score 0):

Put an event listener in the component lifecycle:

```
componentDidMount() {
  var component = this;
  $('.contentImage').click(function(e){
    component.blowUpImage(e.target.id);
  })
}
```

Then you don't need the `onClick` part in the html :)